# Creating database access denied

Tags: permissions, mysql, root, database

Here is what I've done:

```
user@name /my/path # mysql -u root -p<myPassword>  
mysql> create database spy;
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './spy' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

How can I fix it?

Noted that this also happens:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 29 (HY000): File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because **mysql** user does not have permissions to access your datadir. Please execute the below command to fix the issue :

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

**Note :** I am assuming that your datadir is **/var/lib/mysql**.